# Concatenate 2 lines with different fields filled

Tags: csv, awk, text-processing

I'm formatting a log file that I will need to convert to CSV so I can work out a report for higher ups.
In the log files I get something like this:

`Apr 15 15:51:41 server l2tps: [l2tp_l-22] RADIUS: Accounting user 'USER' (Type: 1)`

`Apr 15 15:51:35 server l2tps: [l2tp_l-22] RADIUS: Accounting user 'USER' (Type: 2)`

And in the CSV I'm working on I will need something like this:

```
    User |  Date  | Conected on | Disconected On | Connection Time
User     | 15-Apr |   15:51:35   |     15:51:41    |    00:00:06
```

I already got to the point where I have 2 lines with either the Conection or Disconection time filled, with tabs separating the fields. I already sorted the lines by timing, so in the long list I have in order Conection>Disconection>Conection>Disconection... and so on.

I'm at a loss on how can I concatenate 2 consecutive lines not overwriting filled fields. Essentialy I have 2 lines like this:

`USER [TAB] 15-Apr [TAB] 15:51:35 [TAB] [TAB]`

`USER [TAB] 15-Apr [TAB] [TAB] 15:51:41 [TAB]`

And I need to turn that into:

`USER [TAB] 15-Apr [TAB] 15:51:35 [TAB] 15:51:41 [TAB]`

And I can't for the life of me figure that out.

TLDR: I have 2 lines with field separated data and I need to consolidate both lines into one where there are blank fields. How do I do that?

Can someone help me?

Comment: Hi Rafael, your question is not clear. Please edit it to make it clearer and also mention what is `\tr`.

Comment: Done. Added TLDR and corrected \tr to [TAB].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '
    BEGIN{FS=OFS="\011"}  #Sets field separators to tab
    j{x=$4;$0=j;$4=x;j=0} #If j!=0, set line=j (the line before) and put the 4th field of this line in it
    $4~/^[ ]*$/{j=$0}     #If 4th field is empty, j=thisline
    !j                    #If j=0, print the line
' input
```

Even with comments, the above snippet might be hard to grasp if you've never given awk a try before. Feel free to ask for clarification.

---

On this input file:

```
$ cat -T input
USER ^I 15-Apr ^I 15:51:35 ^I ^I
USER ^I 15-Apr ^I ^I 15:51:41 ^I
```

The produced output is

```
$ cat -T <(./script)
USER ^I 15-Apr ^I 15:51:35 ^I 15:51:41 ^I
```

Comment: Damn straight what I needed! I've been using awk but I'm novice in it still. Hadn't had the opportunity to use BEGIN, until now. Thanks my man!